# what is the difference between element attribute and component attribute in React <Route><Route/> tag

Tags: reactjs, routes

Case 1: when using element attribute within Route tag

```
const App = () => {
  return(
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/album" element={<Album />} />
    </Routes>
  )
};
```

Case 2: when using component attribute within Route tag

```
const App = () => {
  return(
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" component={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/album" component={<Album />} />
    </Routes>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The current documentation of react-router says all there options basically does the same thing, but they leave them in order to **Support older versions**, but you can only use one of those.

[image: react-router-documentation]

Comment: This is valid only for **v5** documentation, **v6** documentation strictly uses "element" instead of those three.

Comment: Correct, thank you, in v6 it's all migrated to the element prop.
ref: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5

Answer (score 1):

**You are probably using a version equal to or greater than v5.1**

#### According to migration [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5), you can use `element` safely everywhere.

*"It will be easier to make the switch to React Router v6 if you upgrade to v5.1 first. In v5.1, we released an enhancement to the handling of  elements that will help smooth the transition to v6. **Instead of using  and  props, just use regular element  everywhere and use hooks to access the router's internal state.**"*

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: when using element attribute within Route tag, you have to specify your component name within tag.ex:(element={<.../>}).

```
const App = () => {
  return(
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/album" element={<Album />} />
    </Routes>
  )
};
```

Case 2: when using component attribute within Route tag, you can simply write your component name in curly braces doesn't need to add tag.ex:(component={...}).

```
const App = () => {
  return(
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/album" component={Album} />
    </Routes>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The main diffrences between element and component attributes;
First:It will be easier to make the switch to React Router v6 if you upgrade to v5.1
Second:element attribute gives oppurtunity to use props but in component attribute you cant.

```
<Routes>
 <Route path='/home' element={<Home prop={"somedata"}/>}/>
 <Route path='/about' Component={About} >
</Routes>
```